# React filter() method not working with if/else

Tags: reactjs, arrays, if-statement, filter

I have an array of products that I get from the api
example :

```
[{id: 1 , title: "TV" , category: "electronics"} {id: 2 , title: "Rigg" , category: "Jewelery"}]
```

where I map this products and show them to the homepage I want the user to be able to search by title. filter by category and sort by price.
I am trying the search and the filter by category(electronics or jewelery) but it doesn't work

```
 products?.filter((prods) => {
              if (searchedInput === "") {
                return prods;
              } else if (
                prods.title
                  .toLocaleLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchedInput.toLocaleLowerCase())
              ) {
                return prods;
              } else if (categorySelected.electronics) {
                return prods.category === Category.Electronics;
              }
              else if (categorySelected.jewelery) {
                return prods.category === Category.Jewelery;
              }
            })
            .map((product) => {
              return (
                <ProductCard ...
```

Now the search works but the filter by category no. and if I remove the search filter and leave  only the categories filter they work , but they don't work together. Maybe I messed up the if else. Any ideas?

Comment: Apply each filter one by one, first filter by categories, then filter by search

Comment: The filter() method creates a new array filled with elements that pass a test provided by a function. So 1) you should have a default else case to return false. 2) you can return true for first if and if-else condition.

Answer (score 0):

You put all conditions in else if so one condition is true then return that value not looking for the next one so you have to make all first in if conditions to check this.

Comment: When I make them all if's only the search works and not the category filter

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes:

- `filter` iterates over each item and decides whether to filter or not (a boolean function), so instead of `prods` each item is just a `product`. And returning the item is the same as returning `true`.
- You can combine all matching conditions into one to make it easier to read and prevent your `if` blocks from only matching one condition:

```js
products?.filter(product => (
    searchedInput === "" ||
    product.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(searchedInput.toLocaleLowerCase()) || 
    categorySelected.electronics && product.category === Category.Electronics ||
    categorySelected?.jewelery && product.category === Category.Jewelery
))
```

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested but doesn't work, categorySelected is a boolean that is true if the user selected a category. so i think you meant product.category === Category.Jewelery. in Category.Jewelery the Category is an enum with the category names from the api

Comment: Updated & should work now.

Comment: The search works but not the categoires. if i have only the category filter in if else like before it works , but your way even if i filter only by categories it dont wort

Comment: How are you storing/updating `categorySelected`?

Comment: categorySelected is a state , that on click i set it from false to true. even if i make const [categorySelected, setCategorySelected] = useState({
    electronics: false,
    jewelery: false,
    mens: false,
    womens: false,
  });  ,, but even if i set one of them manually to true it doesnt show only that category if the filter is constructed like in the examples up there

Comment: If you're hardcoding it and the filter isn't working that means `product.category` isn't matching `Category.Electronics` or `Category.Jewelery` lol. I have no idea know what these values are.

Comment: no the Category.Electronics is correct. is an Category is an enum and the values are right. cause if put there only the category filter it works , but when ther is the search filter and categories filters then it doesnt work anymore